# UnimplementedFeatureError in Ethereum Solidity

Tags: arrays, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am studying ethereum and solidity in recent days.
When I am working with arrays of string, I got below error.

```
UnimplementationFeatureError: Nested dynamic arrays not implemented here
```

I used the arrays like below.

```
string[] public data;
```

What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In solidity, it considered string as a dynamic array. So `data` is considered as a nested dynamic array. That's the reason.

The bridge between two languages does not support to transfer of nested dynamic array.

It's not an issue with solidity. And also it is not necessarily an issue with javascript or other languages.

It's an issue with communication between the two languages.